# setting a variable on completion of an bg task in ubuntu linux 11.10 64bit shell

Tags: linux, sh, ubuntu-11.10

so I have this code:

```
uthreads=4                                                                                                            
x=1                                                                                                                   

cd ./wxWidgets/wxWidgets/build-win                                                                                    

for upxs in $(ls ./lib/*.dll)                                                                                         
do                                                                                                                    
    while [ true ] ; do                                                                                           
            if [ $x -lt $uthreads ] ; then                                                                        
                    x=$((x+1))                                                                                    
                    (upx -qqq --best --color $upxs; x=$((x-1))) &                                                 
                    break                                                                                         
            fi                                                                                                    
            sleep 1                                                                                               
    done                                                                                                          
done                                                                                                                  
x=$((x=1))
```

the problem lies in the variable being modified in parenthesis. Naturally this does not work as intended as the variable never gets sent back to the parent shell. So my question is how do you do this? The variable must be incremented after the upx command finishes regardless of it's exit status. so a simple && or || won't work here. and you can't use a single & here after upx; because then the process runs in the background and instantly changes the variable...

So I'm effectively stuck and could use some help...

Comment: You should probably change 'linux' in the title + tags to whatever shell you're using to get some better answers.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you're trying to 'gate' the activity of a program by controlling how many copies of it are running in the background, check out the `xargs` command. My system doesn't have `upx` installed, so the best I can recommend as a code sample is

```
uthreads=4                                                                                                            
cd ./wxWidgets/wxWidgets/build-win

ls ./lib/*.dll | xargs -I{} -P $uthreads upx -qqq --best --color {} 
   ^                    ^    ^           ^   ^                   ^
   +>your list          |    |           |   |                   |
                        |    |           |   |                   +> item from your lst
                        |    |           |   +> your cmd's opts
                        |    |           +> your cmd
                        |    + xargs opt for # of processes
                        + xargs  option to indicate what string to replace with
```

use `xargs --help` to see all the options, `man xargs` if you're lucky for in-depth detail on usage, and search on web and here for more examples of usage. The [wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Xargs) is a good start.

I hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

first of all, this: `while [ true ]` is wrong, `true` is a command and so is `[` you don't need both here just do `while true; do` (and use `[[` in bash, the other is just for POSIX-sh).

this: `for upxs in $(ls ./lib/*.dll)` is also wrong, and it's more serious; I'll give you some links with information about all that but for now just do: `for upxs in ./lib/*.dll`

another important mistake is that you're not quoting your variables, EVERY SINGLE VARIABLE **MUST** BE DOUBLE QUOTED, if there's anything you learn from this post please let it be that.

now regarding your particular problem the whole approach is wrong, you can't do what you're trying to do because you don't know which process will end first and you wait for a particular one or wait for all of them.

also notice you're running four processes with the *same* file, I'm sure your intention was to process 4 different files in parallel and you don't wait for them to finish either, chances are after your script ends your processes get killed.

the suboptimal but easy solution would be to have 4 processes running in parallel and wait for all of them to finish before starting 4 more, that is accomplished by this (which is similar to your current approach):

```
#!/bin/bash

uthreads=4

cd ./wxWidgets/wxWidgets/build-win
upxs=(lib/*.dll)

i=0
while ((i<${#upxs[@]})); do
    for ((x=0; x<uthreads; x++)); do
        [[ ${upxs[i+x]} ]] || break
        upx -qqq --best --color "${upxs[i+x]}" &
    done
    i=$((i+x))
    wait
done
```

now, this might not be enough to satisfy you :) so the way to implement 4 running processes at all times would be this (using PIDs):

```
#!/bin/bash

uthreads=4

cd ./wxWidgets/wxWidgets/build-win
upxs=(lib/*.dll)

i=0 pids=()
while [[ ${upxs[i]} ]]; do
    while ((${#pids[@]}<uthreads)); do
        upx -qqq --best --color "${upxs[i]}" & pids+=($!)
        [[ ${upxs[++i]} ]] || break
    done
    sleep .1
    pids=($(for pid in "${pids[@]}"; do kill -0 $pid && echo $pid; done))
done
wait
```

now here's the links I promised:

- http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashPitfalls#if_.5Bgrep_foo_myfile.5D
- http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/001
- http://mywiki.wooledge.org/Quotes
- http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ProcessManagement